# Adding another project but it is not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and I am trying to work on two projects at a time, So what I did is add another project and the new project came up next to the old project but when I printed something on new project and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>, the old one's code kept on running not the new one. HELP!

For Ex:
(PROJECT 1)

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
Console.WriteLine(a+b);
//Pressed Ctrl+F5
//Output comes: 3
```

NOW ADDING ANOTHER PROJECT(File->Add->Add Project)
(PROJECT 2 APPEARS NEXT TO THE PROJECT 1 TAB)

```
//Started Coding in Project 2
string a="10";
string b="50";
Console.WriteLine(a+b);
//Pressed Ctrl+F5
//Still Output comes: 3 And NOT 1050
```

Summing all things up, how can I run project which I want to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**Set your new project (PROJECT 2) as startup project**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx):

1.In Solution Explorer, select the desired startup project within your solution (`PROJECT 2` for example).

2.On the `Project` menu (or right-click on the selected project and), choose `Set as StartUp Project`.